# Food safe basic polyelectrolytes?

Tags: acid-base, polymers

Pectin is an example of a food safe polyelectrolyte. It acts as an acid because it is a proton donor and develops negative charges along the polymer.

Can you think of any examples of food safe polyelectrolytes that act as bases and develop positive charges along the polymer?

Comment: I voted to close this as "Too Broad," but I also upvoted it, because I think you may be trying to ask something like "Is there any reason there can't be a food safe polyelectrolyte?" and I think that's a good question.

Comment: Humans (mammals?) like to eat stuff that is neutral or somewhat acidic. Basic stuff tastes more or less disgusting. Exception proving the rule are artisan indigenous specialities like the notorious fermented fish that some Scandinavians reputedly eat.

Comment: Gum arabic is negatively charged at pH above 2,3 and I believe there might be a synergy there. All depends on what application are you thinking of, or is it just an academic question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pectin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pectin) is a heteropolysaccharide rich in [galacturonic acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-galacturonic_acid):

[image]

The carboxylic acid in galacturonic acid gives pectin the ionizable character. Pectin can react with bases to form carboxylate anions along the polysaccharide chain.

There exists a sugar-derivative and polysaccharide with opposite behavior - they react with acids to produce cations along the polysaccharide chain. The modified sugar is [glucosamine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glucosamine), and the polysaccharides are [chitin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chitin) and chitosan(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chitosan). The amine ($\ce{NH2}$) group on glucosamine is basic and will react with acids to become cationic.

[image]

Glucosamine is used as a dietary supplement, and chitin and chitosan are found in various foods, like fungi and shellfish.